# Official Android Swipe / Tabs Example Includes Deprecated Functionality: Is there an alternative sample?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabs

I'm a long-time Windows developer who is now doing Android development.
I would like to use the exact functionality contained in the following officially documented example on tabs and swipe:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

**Deprecated Functionality**

However, the downloadable example contains methods & functionality which is deprecated.

I'm confused about why the Android official example which shows how to handle tabs and swiping ends up including code which is deprecated.

Is it not the most recent version?

**What Functionality Am I Looking For?**

I'll show you two screen shots which display tabs and allow the user to select the tabs to navigate among them or swipe left or right to move through them.
Looks like the following:
[image: Tab 1 (main form)]
[image: Tab 2 (main form)]

I want the user to be able to easily switch between the two tabs and I have a plan to indicate to the user that information on the other tab has been updated by displaying an icon on the current tab.

**My Main Question**

> Is there a similar example which does not include these deprecated
>   methods?

**Related Questions**

If I choose to implement the code in my application -- because the solution is quite beautiful and looks easy to implement -- what will the consequences be?

1. Does it mean that some time in the future the application wouldn't even work properly?
2. Does it mean that it may not work on some devices (API versions)?

Here's some of the code which is deprecated:

actionBar.<strike>setNavigationMode</strike>(ActionBar.<strike>NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS</strike>);
mViewPager.<strike>setOnPageChangeListener</strike>(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
actionBar.<strike>setSelectedNavigationItem</strike>(position);

actionBar.<strike>addTab</strike>();

actionBar.<strike>newTab</strike>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the deprecated functionality is actually related to the ActionBar.

After quite a bit of searching, I found a better example of what I wanted -- sans ActionBar and sans deprecated functionality :
http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html

When you get to that page, you will see that there is no documentation for the subject.  It's odd.  Look very closely in the upper right corner and you'll see a download link which will allow you to download a sample.  It looks like:
[image: download link]

The sliding tab solution is even more elegant and does not include any deprecated functionality.
Here's what it looks like:
[image: tabslider without deprecated functionality]

The example is fantastic, because you can traverse through the tabs by swiping the bottom panel.  Or you can click any of the tabs to move to the associated tab.

Also, the example gives you some more fucntionality above the tabs with the Show Log menu item which switches out the top portion.
Definitely worth a look and this answers my question.

Hope this helps someone else who is looking.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused about why the Android official example which shows how to handle tabs and swiping ends up including code which is deprecated.

Not all documentation gets updated. There has been stuff that has been out of date for years on the site, and despite filing issues, it does not get fixed. This is not unique to Android; it is reasonably commonplace in software development.

> Is it not the most recent version?

It is the most recent version.

> Is there a similar example which does not include these deprecated methods?

I do not know what qualifies as an "example". There are many, many implementations of tabs for `ViewPager`, both from Google ([`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)) and from third parties (about half of the entries in [the "View Pagers" category in the Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111)). Some of those third-party libraries have sample projects as part of their repositories.

> Does it mean that some time in the future the application wouldn't even work properly?

Quite possibly, particularly depending upon your definition of "work properly". We have no means of knowing exactly what will happen in the future (as we used up our last flux capacitor a week ago). Deprecated stuff usually keeps working, but it is at somewhat greater risk of bugs simply due to no longer being aggressively maintained. In the case of action bar tabs, the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport does not support them at all.